# How to calculate $\int\frac{x}{1+\cos^2{x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What's the value of it?I hope you can help me.

$$\int\frac{x}{1+\cos^2{x}}dx$$

You are right.Actually what really wanted is a definite integral .In fact,it's
$$\int_{-\pi}^r\frac{x(1+\sin{x})}{1+\cos^2{x}}dx$$
But I still don't know how to value it.
Thank Q for your reply.

Comment: [See this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5Bx%2F%281%2Bcos%5E2x%29%5D) . Maybe it's what u want or it maybe a definite integral.

Comment: If you want some value, you need a definite integral...

Comment: Is the $r$ in the upper limit $\pi$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x(1+\sin(x))}{1+\cos^2(x)} dx$$
Replacing $x$ by $-x$, we get that
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{-x(1-\sin(x))}{1+\cos^2(x)} dx$$
Adding both and dividing by $2$, we get that
$$I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx = 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\int_0^{\pi}x\sin(x) \cos^{2k}(x) dx$$
Now integral $$\int_0^{\pi}x\sin(x) \cos^{2k}(x) dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2k+1}$$
Hence, we get that
$$I = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \dfrac{2\pi}{2k+1} = \dfrac{\pi^2}2$$

Comment: Thank Q !I always think about integral but not defenite.

Comment: $\int_0^{\pi}x\sin(x) \cos^{2k}(x) \,\mathrm dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2k+1}$ can be proven using the substitution $x\to\pi -x$